# Alternative to List aggregation function in MySQL GROUP BY statement

Tags: mysql, database, list, group-concat

Since the `List function` [is missing in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) functionalities and the `GROUP_CONCAT` in combination with `GROUP BY` function does not perform the same output result of List aggregation function, I wanna know if there is a good alternative that can group integer/string as a list of values with the exact output format (better if **type Collection**, or an ideal format for an easy conversion to the same kind of data type) expected in the column that I have aggregated.

And also if someone can explain me which is the main different between `List` and `GROUP_CONCAT` functions, since at a first look the data result seems identical (**almost...I notice some discrepancies in the values order**).

Here below some screenshot that can clarify the concept of my doubts:

#### List function data result

[image: List]

#### GROUP_CONCAT function data result

[image: GROUP_CONCAT]

#### GROUP_CONCAT function data result after list conversion

[image: GROUP_CONCAT after LIST]

After the conversion of the `GROUP_CONCAT` function data result in a type Collection (in the same format of `List` function data result), when I process the data list results obtained from each sources on the same operation steps the final result is different. So I miss something for sure. Maybe the order of each elements of the list..

Any ideas?

Comment: You can change the order - e.g: `GROUP_CONCAT(field ORDER BY some_field ASC)`. The only other thing I can think of is repeating values, but I don't know what `List` did with those (you can use `DISTINCT` to get rid of them).

Comment: Hi @Vatev thank you for your reply. I have already tried to group values with `ORDER BY`. Unfortunately if you take a look to the List function data result you will notice that it doesn't follow a precise order. For example Row3 and Row4 have a different order, one ascending and one descending.

Comment: they might be ordered by something else, otherwise (assuming it makes a difference for your app) you would get random results.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you always need to request ordering to get data in a specific order. If an ORDER BY clause is not defined the ordering of the result is undefined.

I have seen the List function in Sybase, but it is a vendor extension and if I recall correctly you need to order by if you need specific ordering of the results.

Comment: Hi @Mikpa I think that in mySQL when the ORDER BY clause is not specified the ordering of the result is set by default as ASC. Regarding the `List` function I don't know how it works when it sorts the data unlike the `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

Comment: No, that is not correct. I have had the need to add sorting to get in asc order on group_concat